# Magento2 Multi-store category / product customization

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-vendor

I'm looking to make the change to Magento2 from a custom system and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way possible to share products / categories between stores with minor changes.  All stores will be on the same domain / server.

What I'd like to be able to do is have a primary public store and:

Create a product category (pants)

Create several products (A, B, C) in the category pants

Then create a sub-store on the same server with access to the same category / products.  From there I'd like to make small updates to the category / products that are specific to the sub-store I've added (images, branding info, special descriptions / coupons).

After that I'd like to have other sub-stores that can customize those aspects in a different way.

Is it possible to do this without re-creating the category / products?  I'm having difficulties in my searches around this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Bundle 5 Offer for Medma Marketplace plugins that offers you a brilliant list of 5 extension that is useful in day to day use in your E-commerce business.

http://magento-development.medma.net/medma-magento2-marketplace.html

Medma Marketplace
Medma Matix
Medma Three E-mail
Medma One Step checkout
Medma Mobile APPs